# How do I make ActiveMailer always mail me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I use ActiveMailer with a 3rd party mailing provider. To develop my app, I want to actually see the emails that come in, as a user would, in my email client.

So in development mode, instead of disabling email, I want my app to send the mails, but change the "to" field so that every email is sent to me. Is that possible?

**Update**: I want to test the full route my email takes: going through my ESP, arriving in my inbox, viewing it in gmail. I'm not looking to just test that an email is created.

Comment: Why not just attach your own email address to a test account then?

Comment: Because we send mail to more than just the account holder. And also it would be too easy to slip up and email customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691116/104021), I went with a different option.

Use the mail_safe gem! As well as providing the functionality from sethvargo's answer, it doesn't require any work other than adding the gem, and it automatically figures out who to email from their .gitconfig.

One important note that I rarely saw mentioned when researching this is that you must use `deliver`, not `deliver!`. The latter doesnt call interceptors (though apparently it still calls observers, if that's helpful).

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) by Ryan Bates, however, if you actually want to **deliver** the mail instead of just viewing it in the browser, there are a number of plugins available that others have already listed. No one, however, has mentioned that you can **very** easily accomplish this using `Interceptors`.

Create a new initializer in your `config/initializers` directory in your Rails app:

```
# config/initializers/development_mail_interceptor.rb
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "[#{message.to}] #{message.subject}"
    message.to = "YOUR_EMAIL@gmail.com"
  end
end
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

This leverages the power of an interceptor on your app. It doesn't configure anything, but rather changes the envelope on the message, altering the `to` and `subject` fields. Replace YOUR_EMAIL with the correct value.

The `self.delivering_email(message)` method is invoked by `ActionMailer`. You are hooking into that method and override the message envelope.

Finally, you register that interceptor iff we are currently in the development environment.

Be sure to restart your server, and all your mail (in Development) will actually be sent to your email.

Comment: Awesome, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it out now!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say that others have suggested plugins for **delivering** mail - it doesn't seem like they have, so perhaps I misunderstand what you mean by "delivering".

Comment: I was referring to viewing mail, not actually delivering it.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider checking out something like [MockSMTP](http://mocksmtpapp.com/) (OS X); instead of modifying your "to" fields, you instead set the mail server for dev mode to the "fake" SMTP server created by the app, and from then on ALL emails (sent to anyone) go instead to the app.

I've never used it myself, but I remember seeing that [the devs at 37signals use it](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2855-the-new-guys-computer).

On other operating systems, you may consider one of the following projects:

- [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) by Ryan Bates - popup a new browser window when an email is sent
- [MailCatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) (mentioned by mu is too short) - runs a fake SMTP server and a web-based interface for viewing mail sent to it
- [mailtrap](https://github.com/mmower/mailtrap) - similar to MockSMTP, has both a mock SMTP server and also a separate viewer program

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to get the email in my inbox. I've updated the question to highlight this.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some trouble and run [MailCatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher). MailCatcher is a simple SMTP server that just grabs outbound email and gives it to you in a simple web interface. Install MailCatcher, add this to your `environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :host => 'localhost', :port => 1025 }
```

Start MailCatcher when you start your Rails server (or use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) or something similar to deal with it), and then go to `http://localhost:1080/` to see the email that your application is sending out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to get the email in my inbox. I've updated the question to highlight this.